# calculating percentiles in aws athena

Tags: sql, case, presto, amazon-athena

result of my query is being used in aws quicksight. even though quicksight offers percentileCont() which does the job for us I want to use it in the query instead of using calculated field.

eventually what I want to do is create a point column where

```
under 25percentile -> 0
under 50 percentile -> 1 
under 75 percentile -> 2
rest -> 3
```

depending on a column that ranges from [a, b].

Right now I find out value at each percentile and manually create a range

```
With table as (
    SELECT *
         , cast(date_diff('day', last_transaction, current_date) as double) as col
)
SELECT *
     , case 
         when col between 0 and 25 then 0
         when col between 26 and 66 then 1
         when col between 67 and 193 then 2
         when col >= 194 then 3
       end as point
  FROM table;
```

however I want to make it dynamic so instead of [0,25] would be something like [min(col), 25percentile(col)].

above query outputs

```
col   point
333     3
166     2
 96     1
 .
```

With NTILE() added Thanks to @Gordon Linoff

```
With table as (
    SELECT *
         , cast(date_diff('day', last_transaction, current_date) as double) as col
)
SELECT *
     , case 
         when col between 0 and 25 then 0
         when col between 26 and 66 then 1
         when col between 67 and 193 then 2
         when col >= 194 then 3
       end as point
      , NTILE(4) over(order by col) as pt
  FROM table;
```

outputs

```
col   point
0     1
0     1
0     1
 .
```

seems to mess up col calculation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are pretty much describing the `ntile()` function:

```
SELECT t.*,,
       NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY col) - 1 as point
FROM table;
```

Two caveats:

- `NTILE(<n>)` returns values between 1 and n
- `NTILE()` makes sure the resulting tiles are equal.  That means that values on the boundaries could end up in different bins.

An alternative that puts values in separate bins (but the bins might have different sizes) is `percent_rank()`.  In your case:

```
SELECT t.*,,
       CEILING(PRECENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col) * 4) - 1 as point
FROM table;
```

Comment: Thanks, however ntile() function seems to break something and when I run ntile() `col` values become messed up. I've updated my code above.

Comment: @Ambleu . . . The numbering for `ntile()` starts at `1`.  That is why this subtracts `1` so it starts at `0` as you desire.

Comment: I know, but why does it mess up `col` calulation?

Comment: @Ambleu . . . It doesn't.  Your query doesn't have an `order by`, so the values are just coming back in a different order than you expect them.

Comment: oh, sorry. Yes you are right I got mixed up with another column. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Presto, I think that [`approx_percentile()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#approx_percentile) and a `case` expression can do what you want:

```
select t.*, 
    case
        when col <= approx_percentile(col, 0.25) over() then 0
        when col <= approx_percentile(col, 0.50) over() then 1
        when col <= approx_percentile(col, 0.75) over() then 2
        else 3
    end as point
from mytable t
```

Comment: doesn't x -> col? not quite understanding where variable x came from

Comment: @Ambleu: indeed. Fixed.

Comment: Now query runs but taking a long time, do you know what might be causing much computation?